# Can I install vlang in Mac OS?

Tags: vlang

V is getting more and more interesting to me, and I'd like to play with it in MacOS. I'm so used to the make/make install paradigm, so naturally after:

```
xcode-select --install
git clone https://github.com/vlang/v
cd v
make
```

I did:

```
make install
```

and got:

```
Please use `sudo v symlink` instead.
```

So I did:

```
sudo v symlink
```

and got:

```
V panic: symlink doesn't exist
```

I'm feeling very stupid. What to do? Thanks super in advance

Comment: The github page seems to have good instructions for installing and sym-linking. I didn't see mention of `make install`, so maybe don't do that. They don't really install anything - it all wants to sit in the repo.  Just make a soft link yourself. I usually just dl the mac build from the releases. (Despite the hype, I didn't find it ready to play with.) Have fun!

Comment: Thanks, @aMike ultimately I got it to work with ./v -- someone on the vlang Discord server helped me out. I'll answer the question here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those who may be running into this problem, here are my notes around the fix:

```
xcode-select --install
git clone https://github.com/vlang/v
cd v
make
sudo ./v symlink
Get the Visual Studio plugin with
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=0x9ef.vscode-vlang
```